How to fix multiple player instance when a player join in Unity with Photon
I'm learning Photon and creating a party quiz game where in a room the host selects a topic and randomly chooses a minigame when the host starts. After the minigame ends, all player will return to the room again with PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(), but if a new player joins or one of the player leaves and rejoin, multiple player instances of the player inside the room appears but only one for the player is moving and I can't seem found the fix for it. Any help would be appreciated.
// For the Room Scene
// After joining the room
void SpawnPlayers() 
{
    Vector2 position = new(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, position, Quaternion.identity);
}

... some code

// Entering to the minigame
[PunRPC]
public void StartGame() 
{
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(minigame);
}

// For the Minigame Scene
// After joining the minigame
void SpawnPlayers()
{
    Vector2 position = new(Random.Range(min.x, max.x), Random.Range(min.y, max.y));
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, position, Quaternion.identity);
}

... some code

void ReturnToRoom() 
{
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Room");
}


Could you post the code that handles the creation of your player objects? Or the OnPlayerJoined callback?

Hey @ipodtouch0218, I have edited my post to include some relevant code for my problem. I hope this would help, thanks.
